# Connect to multiple dnsmasq servers at a time

Tags: 18.04, dns, dnsmasq

I have two dnsmasq servers setup in my network. I added the dns-servers into the my network configurations but i am only able to connect to one of them at a time. When i include the two of them in addition to the route ip[192.168.2.1], i can only connect the the first dnsmasq server added to the left- in this case 192.168.2.150

[image: dns-config]

whyi s this actually happening. I though all the time that one of the dns servers is not working!

I have also another problem that i need to disable and reenable the netwoking of my ubuntu 18.04 each time i add a new host name to the dnsmasq  server and restart the  server.

Comment: DNS is going to work in the order of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd.  Primary, Secondary, Tertiary.  If the first fails to connect or respond it will go to the 2nd, then the 3rd if the 2nd fails.  This is the way DNS is designed.  Are you expecting it to connect to .150 and .249 at the same time for a response?  Also, restarting dnsmasq on the server shouldn't be needed if you restart the networking on your endpoint system..

Comment: for the .150  i am accessing ".foo" domain and on .249 ".boo". So requests to *.foo should actually success and  when i try to access in the browser or via curl example.boo, it should  actually fail on .150 and the request will go to .249 and get a respond. But i am only enable to get a respond for .foo domain and all the requests to .boo are failing with the error  "Could not resolve host".

Comment: That's because of how DNS works.  If DNS gets a response from the first server it wont fail over to the next.  What you need to do is configure the dnsmasq endpoint servers (if possible) to forward requests for domains it doesnt own to other DNS servers that do, on both of the servers.  (Alternatively run a local DNS server on your network using BIND9 and configure forwarder zones to the proper DNS servers for those domains).

Comment: Thansk man :) i configured one of the dnsmasq servers to use the other one and it worked! I really still not understand this thing, you said  "If DNS gets a response from the first server it wont fail over to the next." actually if i try to access example.boo i should not get a response from the first server. It should actually fail over to the next or am i taking this wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The core problem here is how your system handles DNS requests, and by default how most systems do.

When you define DNS servers in your configuration, it goes in order of definition - 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.  Namely, these are the DNS servers to request data from and the order to request the data in *in the event one of the servers fails to reply*.

DNSMasq server A is only aware of domain 'foo' and not domain 'bar'.  It will respond for "foo" and the Internet, but return NXDOMAIN for "bar".  However, **the server still responded to the initial inquiry**, so it won't test your second or third server for any records relating to the NXDOMAIN (Nonexistent Domain, as DNS packets and queries will have internally) because it got a reply.

If DNSMasq Server A doesn't reply at *all* and the attempt to query times out, then the system will query DNSMasq Server B (2nd in order).  It will respond for "bar" domains, but attempting to query "foo" will return NXDOMAIN as above.  Same case here, though, it *responded*, so it won't try your third DNS server for queries.

An NXDOMAIN (Nonexistent Host/Domain) is actually a 'valid reply' from a DNS server.  THe system won't automatically attempt to query DNS server 2 or 3 because it got a response - albeit not the response you want.

In this case, you need to configure your dnsmasq servers so that they know to forward requests for the domain they do not serve to the proper server so it gets a valid reply.  These are called 'forwarder' zones in BIND9 (which is what I utilize), and will forward domain requests in those zones to the proper server for responses.

Configure dnsmasq server A to forward its requests to B for domain "bar" and configure dnsmasq server B to forward its requests to A for domain "foo".

(These use the examples I stated above, use your own domains properly here.)